# unable to run python selenium File "<stdin>", line 1 pythonanywhere

Tags: python, selenium, pythonanywhere

I have just registered on pythonanywhere in order to deploy my python selenium project, but I am having enormous difficulty in executing this code, in fact I am new to linux and I do not know what command to type to execute my program , whatever I type , the console returns me

File "", line 1 pip install ipython ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

here is the link to the screenshot:  https://ibb.co/vXGv6MC

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, you should copy and paste from the terminal, and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) that text like code. Looking at the image, it appears that you are trying to use command-line commands within the Python program. You should not do that. You should use them directly from the terminal, before starting Python.

Comment: You should also make sure you understand both how to use a command line, and how to write some basic Python code, by reading and following tutorials for each, before trying to use an online service like pythonanywhere.

Comment: "in fact I am new to linux and I do not know what command to type to execute my program" Exactly what steps did you follow, in order to get Python to start in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run a `pip install` command, which should be run from Bash, in a Python interpreter.  To use pip on PythonAnywhere, start a Bash console instead of a Python one.  You'll also need to make sure that you're using the right version of `pip` to match the version of Python that you're using -- that is, if you want to run your code with Python 3.9, you should use the `pip3.9` command instead of just `pip`, and you will also need to use the `--user` flag.  See [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) for the details.